# using a password command with wpa_supplicant

Tags: password, wpa-supplicant

On linux, wpa_supplicant is usually brought up by root,
with plaintext password (or PSK, which has basically the same security)
stored in /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf (with 600 permission).

I'd rather not have any password in /etc/wpa_supplicant,
and use a command like "/usr/bin/pass some@email"
to decrypt the password when needed.
The password store to be used is the one of my user though,
so another user would not necessarily have access to that wifi network.

Is something like this possible, either with wpa_s or iwd?